# Any ideas why this code won't work? body > *

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery, jqtouch

I am using jqtouch to make a mobile website. I am also implementing a gallery image slider within the website, however when the gallery is put where I need it (inbetween `<div id="project_name" class="page"></div>`, the images won't display.

After tinkering for hours, removing     display: none; from jqtouch.css rule:

```
body > * {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(0) scale(1);
    min-height: 420px !important;
}
```

Makes the gallery work, but obviously means the website doesn't work. Any ideas why this is happening, what body > * does and how I can get over it?

Project is at http://djrb.co.uk/mobile/portfolio.php#home

Many thanks,

Rich

Comment: (Maybe not relevant, but this is what Chrome says: http://screencast.com/t/vOkecMRyAc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `body > *` matches any element that is a child of `body`. The right-angle bracket is the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). The star [matches any element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching).

You probably want to include a more specific selector for your gallery `div` and apply the appropriate styles in a separate declaration block. Something like this:

```
#project_name {
    /* properties */
}
```

Comment: @lwburk Thanks for your reply, so that style is applied to every single element? Is there anyway of not applying it to my gallery div so that my images display? Cheers

Comment: @Richard, no it will be assigned to every single direct child of body, but no grandchildren. For example `<body><div class="child"><div class="grandchild"></div></div><div class="child"><div class="grandchild"></div></div></body>`. Here, both the divs with a class of 'child' will be selected, but not the divs with a class of 'grandchild', or anything contained inside those grandchildren.

Comment: @lwburk @blowski thanks for your replies. I have tried your update but it didn't change anything. I'm assuming if it works as a child of the body (it works outside of the div with class page), that it needs this style applied to it for it to work properly? I'll give that a go! Always learning - really, thanks guys

Comment: P.S. Tried applying the style to the DIV, with no joy. Have placed the gallery as a body child element (can be viewed on the home page) to demonstrate it working. A real strange one!

Comment: Developed a work around, I'm now linking to another page and retrieving the images on this page. Thanks for your help though guys!